# how to show archived task in many2many tree view on another model in Odoo9?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I'm trying to show the archived tasks (active = False) beside of the active tasks on many2many field view (Project Management Module) on **Odoo9**.

Ok, for a moment i just trying to show the archived tasks (active = False) only, so i've tried this code on my form view xml:

```
<field name="task_ids" widget="one2many_list" mode="tree" domain="[('active', '=', False)]"/>
```

OR

```
<field name="task_ids" widget="one2many_list" mode="tree" context="{'active_test': False,}"/>
```

But, still not working. The field 'task_ids' is still showing only the active tasks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"

Comment: @EJoshuaS 'task_ids' many2many view is still showing only the active tasks.

Comment: This question is already answered in odoo forum so I'm not going to copy-paste. Before asking you should google a bit

Comment: @DachiDarchiashvili sorry, i've google it, then i found the 2 codes above on odoo9..
ive try to implement it, but it still doesnt work..
if i get the link, its better.. thx before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Odoo 9.0**

Here you will have to override the field.
Change the domain of your field in a python file in your module.

```
task_ids = fields.Many2many(
        domain=['|', ('active', '=', False), ('active', '=', True)])
```

Trying to use active_test on Many2many won't work.

Plus, note that `[('active', 'in', [True, False])]` won't work either. Because, whene the automatic active test is made, it will check if `('active', '=', False)` is present. If not, it adds `('active', '=', True)` to filter all archived items by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this domain instead of that:

`<field name="task_ids" widget="one2many_list" mode="tree" domain="[('active', '=', True)]"/>`

It will give u the active tasks only. ALso check whether that field is there or not. It is there by default but still sometimes we have to check is database in particular object.

Hopw this will help you.

Thanks,
Chandni.

Comment: I'm trying to show the Task which active = False (archived). I've tried those above code on my form view xml, but the field 'task_ids' is still showing only the active tasks.